# Parsing Xml feed having multiple different categories

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can anybody please tell me how can I parse the below Feed

http://teluguone.com/movies/moviesXml.php

In MainPage I will Arrange 8 Buttons like Action,
                                          Comedy,
                                          Love  etc as based on different categories given in above feed.
   When I click Action Button.The movies present in the Action Category has to be displayed in listbox.

And similarly when clicked on the other buttons also movies related to that particular categories has to be displayed in ListBox.

Anybody please give me hint how can I parse this feed with different categories.I am not understanding how can I parse these different categories.

I have written the following code to download xml file.Does it works.please tell me.

**MainPage.Xaml:**

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

            <ListBox x:Name="moviesList"  >

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Height="130">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding MovieImage}" 
                                   Grid.Column="0" 
                                   Width="97" 
                                   Height="125" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               Margin="6"/>
                        <StackPanel Margin="10,15,0,0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Height="60"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MovieName}" 
                                       FontSize="30" />

                        </StackPanel>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

**Mainpage.xaml.cs:**

```
        namespace PhoneApp1
        {
        public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
       {
            // Constructor
            public MainPage()
           {
              InitializeComponent();
              // is there network connection available
               if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No network connection available!");
            return;
        }
        // start loading XML-data
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://teluguone.com/movies/moviesXml.php", UriKind.Absolute);
        downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(MoviesDownloaded);
        downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    }

    void MoviesDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
        }
        else
        {
            // Deserialize if download succeeds
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Movies));
            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
            Movies movies = (Movies)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
            moviesList.ItemsSource = movies.Collection;
        }
       }
    }
   }
```

**Movie.cs:**

```
 public class Movie
        {
             [XmlElement("MovieName")]
             public string MovieName { get; set; }

             [XmlElement("MovieActor")]
             public string MovieActor { get; set; }

             [XmlElement("MovieActress")]
             public string MovieActress { get; set; }

             [XmlElement("MovieDirector")]
             public string MovieDirector { get; set; }

             [XmlElement("MovieImage")]
             public string MovieImage { get; set; }

  }
```

**Movies.cs:**

```
    [XmlRoot("Movies")]
    public class Movies
  {
    [XmlArray("movies")]
    [XmlArrayItem("movie")]
    public ObservableCollection<Movie> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

ManyThanks in Advance

Comment: what's going wrong with your code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534510/xml-deserialize-in-windows-phone-c-sharp

Comment: Please anybody help me with this feed.I was not knowing how to parse these different categories.Hope anybody gives me a hint of this.

Answer (score 0):

First understand basic XML structure and write properties based on that. Its very long to describe here, hence I have uploaded my sample project "XML deserialization into C# objects" in GitHub and refer for more info.

Step 1: Write properties based on XML Structure, which your retrieve from Source.

Step 2: Download the XML string using WebClient or Http class.

Step 3: Deserialize those strings using XMLSerializer and bind it to objects.

Step 4: Get respective terms using providing search options from objects.

You can refer my [GitHub Project here](https://github.com/BalasubramaniM/WindowsPhone-Projects/tree/master/ReadXMLintoObjects).

Comment: I have posted my code to download the file.please tell me does it works.Thank you sir.I was trying and trying to follow your project.

Comment: I didnt get any errors but nothing was displaying.Blank screen was appearing in emulator.And I was unable to understand how to get the categories seperatly such as action,love,comedy etc

Comment: In my suggestion, use checkbox to separate categories. Use breakpoints and check whether you get data first. Let me check your code once.

Comment: Sir, how can I use checkbox?Can you give me any hint.